# Need guide with how to use flutter custom notification UI

Tags: flutter

I have implemented getInitialMessage, onMessage and onMessageOpenedApp methods and notifications are coming into the system but I am not able to find a guide on how to use custom notifications UI.

I don't want to use awesome_notifications as there is no update since 8 months plus it again has a dependency on awesome_notifications_fcm(last updated 8 months ago).